# Can you access PCI cards(32 bits) in "real mode"?

Tags: pci

Can you access PCI cards(32 bits) in "real mode" ? Isn't "real mode" 16 bits? I have a developer claiming he can only access hardware in Real mode.  But PCI is 32bits...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

IO ports 0xCF8 and 0xCF9 act as index and data registers for accessing PCI Config space. The address to be written to index register (i.e. 0xCF8) has a fixed predefined format (refer PCI spec). To access pci config data, one writes to index register and then reads from data register.

```
The Index register is a DWORD (32-bit) register and the format is:

Byte-3 = 0x80
Byte-2 = Bus No
Byte-1 = Upper 5 bits as DEVICE no, and lower 3 bits as FUNCTION no.
Byte-0 = Register no. to read from config space
```

So to read from Bus:0 Device:0 Func:0 register:0 in real mode, you would say:

```
IoPortWrite32(0xCF8, 0x80000000);
ValueRead = IoPortRead32(0xCFC);
```

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
Rohit